# Arrow function is null inside tagged template literal function

Tags: javascript, jsx, styled-components

I'm trying to decipher how styled components work. I get most parts, but interpolations.
Consider this component:

```
const display = 'flex'

const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
  color: ${(props) => props.color};
  display: ${display};
`
```

The function that receives the styles is something like this:

```
const styled = {
   div: (string, ...values) => {
      return ({children, ...props}) => {
        const styles = tag(string, props, ...values);
        return <div style={styles}>{children}</div>
      }
    }
}
```

string in this case is: `["\n   background-color: red;\n   color: ",";\n   display: ",";\n"]`

values are logged as: `[null,"flex"]`

The first interpolation (the arrow function) is null.

How does styled-components manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is working properly in Chrome. I tried it inside a playground in VSCode where I got the null value.